# how to prevent tags from word wrapping?

Tags: css, tags, word-break, nowrap

I have a well of tags that I don't want to word-wrap, but I **do** want to have the list of tags wrap. 
For example:

```
[first] [second thing] [yet another thing]
```

what I DONT want is:

```
[first] [second 
thing] [yet another thing]
```

ie breaking **within** the tag.

what I DO want is like this:

```
[first] [second thing] 
[yet another thing]
```

I've messed with

```
word-break: break-word;
/* white-space: nowrap; */
```

on the parent and child, without any success.
either the whole field just ends up as one line - with no breaking at all, or I get breaks within the tags.

currently I have this:

```
.tag-box {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.tag {
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;  
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 200%;
  /* word-break: break-word; */
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle and try to resize the result section window by dragging it to the right http://jsfiddle.net/5fev6o2p/4/

Comment: I doubled the tags and still working http://jsfiddle.net/5fev6o2p/5/

Comment: awesome thanks! it was that inline-block i was missing...

Comment: if you want to make this an answer happy to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fev6o2p/6/

CSS code:

```
.tag-box {
  word-break: break-word;
}

.tag {
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;  
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 200%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tag-box">
  <li class="tag">[first]</li>
  <li class="tag">[second thing]</li>
  <li class="tag">[third thing]</li>
  <li class="tag">[yet another thing]</li>
  <li class="tag">[first]</li>
  <li class="tag">[second thing]</li>
  <li class="tag">[third thing]</li>
  <li class="tag">[yet another thing]</li>
</ul>
```